# Excel run-time error when copying all worksheets into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Very new with excel vba, just wanted to ask why I am getting the runtime error on the With wb.Sheets("i")line. How it supposed to work is it should open the file and copy all 6 worksheets into the designated workbook. The with function is trying to get and copy the header only for first worksheet and not to copy the header on the next one.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim lcurrow As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("/Users/Documents/2020-06-22.xlsx")

For i = 1 To 6 Step 1

With wb.Sheets(i)
            If i = 1 Then
            lrow = 1
            Else
            lrow = 2
            End If
            
Do Until .Range("A" & lrow).Value = vbNullString

lcurrow = lcurrow + 1

For n = 0 To 3 Step 1

wb.Sheets(i).Range("A" & lcurrow).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value = .Range("A" & lrow).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value

Next n

lrow = lrow + 1

Loop
            
End With


Next i

Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You should write ``With wb.Sheets(i)`` (without double-quotes) for indexing access. Please review basic syntax for a variable.

Comment: You're using i as a string literal by enclosing it in double quotes ... that is ... it is trying to refer to a sheet with the name "i":. Try Sheets(i) ... no double quotes.

Comment: With wb.Sheets(i) still gives the same error

Comment: So what exactly is the runtime error you're getting? And can you confirm that there are (at least) 6 worksheets in the workbook being opened?

Comment: Sorry, my error is Object variable or With block variable not set - Error 91. Just to confirm, I am trying to make the macro grab the first 6 worksheets (out of the 8) and extract it to a new workbook.

Comment: When debugging, it says - wb.Sheets(i) = <Object Variable or With block variable not set>

Comment: You're just copying data from `wb.Sheets(i)` to `wb.Sheets(i)`  Where is the data supposed to be going?

Comment: Hi Tim, it is supposed to go to a new workbook. So the goal is to run the macro and extract worksheet 1-6 from that workbook, to a new workbook (separate from data extracted).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all the worksheets in a workbook you can do

```
  For each ws in wb.sheets
        'your code you want to do on each worksheet here

  Next ws
```